# SVN on Team Foundation Server - Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, svn, tfs, delphi-2010

We're looking to upgrade to Delphi 2010 and have Team Foundation Server as our source Control.

Is there a plug in for TFS that allows clients to talk to it via SVN?

I noticed that CodePlex, Microsoft's open source web service, supports TFS and SVN so am hoping that there is a SVN plug in for TFS.

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at the [SvnBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) project, which is I believe what Codeplex are using

Comment: Make sure to build from the latest source.  They have been working a lot on improving SVN support but it hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi used to support MSSCCI for version control plugins.  If it still does you would be able to use the TFS MSSCCI provider and get TFS integration without using SvnBridge.